# customizing tumblr's new photoset layout

Tags: templates, layout, block, photo, tumblr

I'm trying to work with tumblr's custom photoset layout. I was checking out this post here for some documentation: http://staff.tumblr.com/post/7615038792/photoset-redux

I'm trying to figure out how to use js array block to create new layouts based on how many images are in the photoset. To be honest I'm not completely sure how these features are supposed to work but if someone can provide some answers or a tutorial I would be greatly appreciative.

Comment: You can take the `{JSPhotosetLayout}` and then manipulate the images on the page with that number. If you want to see an example of that, check out this plugin I had a hand in developing: https://github.com/PixelUnion/Extended-Tumblr-Photoset/blob/master/js/pxuPhotoset.js You can see it can get a bit complex!

Answer (score 0):

I found some code on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/7Mee1spB), which seems to be what you're looking for here

I'm using the slightly messier code (but with working CSS/HTML provided) unearthed [on Github Gists](https://gist.github.com/xles/6201497) which will partition the images into rows,

```
{block:Photoset}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var layout = {JSPhotosetLayout};
        var photocount = 0;
        var photoclass = '', photos = [];
        for(var i=0;i<layout.length;i++) {
            switch(layout[i]) {
                case "1":
                    photoclass = 'col-lg-12';
                    break;
                case "2":
                    photoclass = 'col-lg-6';
                    break;
                case "3":
                    photoclass = 'col-lg-4';
                    break;
                case "4":
                    photoclass = 'col-lg-3';
                    break;
            }
            for(var j=0; j < parseInt(layout[i]); j++) {
                photos[photocount] = {
                    'class': photoclass,
                    rowsize: parseInt(layout[i])
                };
                photocount++;
            }
        }
        photocount = 0;
        var rowcount = 0;
    </script>

    {block:Photos}
        <script>
            if(rowcount == 0) {
                document.write('<div class="row">');
            }
        </script>

        <div id="photosetphoto" class="col-lg-3">
            <script>
                var photo = document.getElementById('photosetphoto');
                photo.className = photos[photocount].class;
                photo.removeAttribute('id');
                rowcount++;
            </script>
            <div class="thumbnail center">
                        {LinkOpenTag}
                <img src="{PhotoURL-1280}" alt="{PhotoAlt}" class="img-responsive">
                {block:Caption}
                    <div class="caption">
                        {Caption}
                    </div>
                {/block:Caption}
                        {LinkCloseTag}
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            if(rowcount == photos[photocount].rowsize) {
                document.write('</div>');
                rowcount = 0;
            }
            photocount++;                                        
        </script>
    {/block:Photos}
    {block:Caption}
        <div class="caption">{Caption}</div>
    {/block:Caption}
{/block:Photoset}
```

and then it only takes a little added Javascript to resize the images as whatever % of the total width given to the photoset with

```
var photosetPics = document.querySelectorAll('div.col-lg-6 div.thumbnail img')
    for (i=0;i<photosetPics.length;i++) {
      var rowLength = photosetPics[i].parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll('div div.thumbnail img').length;
      photosetPics[i].parentNode.parentNode.setAttribute('style','width:'+100/rowLength+'%')
}
```

That's actually come out pretty ugly but it runs... It can clearly be done more elegantly using the code above which delineates different "cases" but to be honest I like the simple % method and will probably remove the cases and just stick to navigating the DOM to change the widths instead.

Lastly, you need to make these div's sit inline (`display:inline-block` had no effect when I tested it),

```
div.col-lg-12, div.col-lg-6, div.col-lg-4, div.col-lg-3 {
  float: left;
}
```

Making this a community wiki since it's not really my code and this would obviously be a good resource for others to build on - please contribute any improvements.

It might be worth noting that this won't cut off the height of images like Tumblr will on the dashboard (that suits me but might not be what others are looking for)